# How to get core to leverage a MySQL master/slave configuration?

Tags: 7, performance, database

I read this question [MySQL master/slave replication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086385/drupal-7-mysql-master-slave-replication-not-working) and its answer:

> Using slave databases is barely implemented in Drupal core. If you are
>   developing your own modules then calls to db_query need to specify
>   that they want to use the slave database using the $options array. See
>   DatabaseConnection::defaultOptions for how to set this array.

Is there a way without <strike>killing kittens</strike> hacking the core to get [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) and [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_select/7) to make more slave SELECT queries ?

By default, these functions will query the master unless specifically told to query the slave (see their API). You have to write `db_query($query, $args, array('target' => 'slave'))` in order to query the slave and the core (and all the modules) aren't written to achieve this.

Only [search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) (see the slave part) and aggregator seems to leverage this.

**Edit:** Oct, 25
I saw pressflow 7 is out but I'm not sure if it helps a lot right now.
I haven't found something relevant so let's try a little bounty to help this getting an answer.

**Edit:** Oct, 31
I'm mainly worried about [Crell's comments](http://groups.drupal.org/node/27820#comment-94430) regarding this topic: [What to do with slaves?](http://groups.drupal.org/node/27820).
Mainly, is there troubles if I send `SELECT` queries to the slave, what happens with delays in the replication and the fact that I may want to do a `node_load()` just after saving a new node.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how I currently implement this.

First you need to set up a SelectQueryExtender class like this:

```
class SlaveTarget extends SelectQueryExtender {
  public function __construct(SelectQueryInterface $query, DatabaseConnection $connection) {
    if ($connection->getTarget() != 'slave') {
      $connection = Database::getConnection('slave', $connection->getKey());
    }
    parent::__construct($query, $connection);
    $this->addTag('SlaveTarget');
  }
}
```

Once you have that, then all you have to do is get all the other queries to extend the extender. :) if that makes sense. Here's the snippet.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 */
function example_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) { 
  if (is_a($query, 'SelectQuery') && !$query->hasTag('SlaveTarget')) {
    $query->extend('SlaveTarget');
  }
}
```

And now all your SelectQuery hit the slave ;-) This is the only way I've been able to accomplish this. Anyways it works great.

Also if you have this on a custom module you can set up the SlaveTarget to be it's on file SlaveTarget.inc and add a files[] = SlaveTarget.inc to your module info file.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answer, what mainly worries me is this thread: [What to do with slaves?](http://groups.drupal.org/node/27820) and [Crell's comment regarding slave](http://groups.drupal.org/node/27820#comment-94430). So is you solution safe in any cases ? Do you restrict some `SELECT` queries ? How do you deal with delays in the replication and the fact that loading a node just after saved it may causes troubles ?

Comment: This is changing the database to slave only on Select queries. This only happens when the query has been written with SelectQuery not db_query so no need to worry about and insert or update being targeted to the slave. We're running this on 3 huge production environments without any problems. I've haven't worried much about the mysql replication as its almost instant (in my case) but I can see how that might be a small issue issue in certain environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it's a great solution, I'll see if this is viable on our environment.

Comment: Eric, is this code out there somewhere as a contrib or sandbox module?

Comment: @paul-m: see https://drupal.org/project/autoslave.

Comment: I have tested this solution, and it either no longer works with Drupal 7, or never worked. I've posted an alternative solution [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/83838/147).

Comment: Yes, it appears even though the connection can be set to "slave", if the query itself doesn't have the `target => 'slave'` option set, it will still run on the default connection. It's a pain it's not easier to set the connection target more easily at the `query_alter` level like `$query->setOption` or `$query->target = 'slave';`

Answer (score 5):

The [AutoSlave](https://drupal.org/project/autoslave) module redirects `SELECT` queries to read-only replicant databases, ***and*** it takes into account replication lag.

According to the module docs, it only uses the read-only replicant when all of the following conditions are true:

> 1. The query is a select query
> 2. The tables in the select query have not been written to during the request and within the assumed replication lag
> 3. A transaction has not been started
> 4. The tables in the select query are not specified in the 'tables' option in the driver settings
> 5. A lock has not been started (core db-lock and memcache-lock supported)

Answer (score 1):

from what I heard at the recent Drupal BADcamp Pressflow is the way to go if you want master/slave configurations. You'll be limited to Mysql as the DB.
Also, checkout the "[high performance group](http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance)" on d.o.

Comment: Currently Pressflow 7 = D7, there's nothing (yet) that Pressflow do that D7 don't :(

Answer (score 1):

Despite all of the amazing work done on the database abstraction layer in Drupal 7, this is still surprisingly difficult to do with Drupal core out of the box. As others have mentioned, [AutoSlave](http://drupal.org/project/autoslave) is an option, although not one I've attempted due to my stubborn refusal to believe that it should be that difficult to do this.

A simpler solution I have found is the following. To route **all** `SELECT`s to the slave server, you create a file titled `select.inc` inside of the core `includes/database/mysql` directory with the following contents:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Select builder for MySQL database engine, routing all SELECTs to the slave.
 */

/**
 * @addtogroup database
 * @{
 */

class SelectQuery_mysql extends SelectQuery {
  public function __construct($table, $alias = NULL, DatabaseConnection $connection, $options = array()) {
    $key = $connection->getKey();
    $connection = Database::getConnection('slave', $key);
    $options['target'] = 'slave';
    parent::__construct($table, $alias, $connection, $options);
  }
}

/**
 * @} End of "addtogroup database".
 */
```

There are some risks with this method:

1. This method will hijack **all** `SELECT`s and direct them to the slave, which will undoubtedly cause issues if you have any lag in replication. Read that sentence again.
2. When you upgrade Drupal core, it is possible that this file will get deleted.
3. If Drupal core were ever to start shipping with its own `includes/database/mysql/select.inc`, your file would get overwritten during upgrade, and you would have to start maintaining your own patched version of the select.inc that ships with Drupal core.

If you don't have any slave servers specified in settings.php, the above code will not cause a problem. It will still gracefully degrade to using the **master** server.

Comment: Yes, it appears even though the connection can be set to "slave", if the query itself doesn't have the `target => 'slave'` option set, it will still run on the default connection. It's a pain it's not easier to set the connection target more easily at the `query_alter` level.